# Jquery library for particular structure of select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question for you, I am looking for the jQuery library that allows proper operation of the structure select which looks something like this:

```
<select name="name['index']['index']">
  ...
</select>
```

or

```
<select name="name['index'][]['index']">
  ...
</select>
```

Typically used the library select2 but that at the moment returns me an error when I want to expand the list:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label [for = name [ 'index'] [ 'index']]

So my question is, do any of you know a library that can cope with such a structure?

Or something like that select2 allows and I did not know and one of you knows how to do it?

Comment: What should mean `name['index'][]['index']` ? all children of this element ?

Comment: There's no need for the quotes around `index`

Comment: @MaciejKozieja 
I want to convert this structure to a nice looking select using the library it doesnt matter what it mean its just a html structure

Comment: @rad11 but it has to have some point to use it

Comment: @MaciejKozieja 
I think we do not understand. I have such a structure selects:

http://pastebin.com/MWj5U8fe

And I want to turn them in select2 or use another library to do this

Comment: @rad11 and you want to select evry node that has ['tag'] ?

Comment: @Pugazh - let's [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) - if you think there's noise in the question, edit the noise out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
const select = (filter, node = document.body) => {
    if (typeof filter == "string") {
        return select(x => x.getAttribute('name') == filter, node)
    } else if (typeof filter == "function") {
        const nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(node, NodeFilter["SHOW_ELEMENT"], {
            acceptNode: node => filter(node) == true ? NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : null
        }), list = []
        let temp
        while (temp = nodeIterator.nextNode()) {
            list.push(temp)
        }
        return list
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
select('name['index'][]['index']')
```

This will check if name attribute is string you specified.
You can also add second param to reduce selection to only children of specific element.

You can also write function to check if like you want, try it your self :D hope it works for you.